# Сделать, чтоб определенные объекты не исчезали при уменьшении масштаба - google map js api v3

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api

Возможно ли на гугл картах сделать, чтобы определенные объекты были видны при любом масштабе? Например, по умолчанию местные дороги исчезают после зума меньше 8, остаются только только автобаны, потом после зума 6 исчезают и автобаны. Так вот можно ли как-то сделать, чтоб все, например, дороги были видны при любом зуме?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Можно изменить цвет, вес, прозрачность и некоторые другие свойства объектов, можно вообще их сделать невидимыми, но видимость в зависимости от зума менять нельзя

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Это почти ответ на вопрос. Настроить оформление карты так что бы оставались только дороги. Стилями удалить все лишнее (логотип, текст и фон). Отрисовать это дело в canvas, а затем уже выводить поверх основной карты. Это все конечно нарушает договоренность об использовании карт.

Answer (score 0):

В данном случае правила отрисовки для объектов задаёт сам Google, где у него прописано, что и при каком масштабе рисовать, на это повлиять не получится.

НО возможность же отрисовки каких-либо объектов при любом масштабе, в принципе, в данных картах имеется, для этого просто необходимо самим их отрисовать.